# AccessibilityNodeInfo of AccessibilityEvent always null on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, accessibility

Im trying to get information about AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED but on samsung devices the AccessibilityNodeInfo is always null

My config:

AccessibilityService.kt

```
 override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?){
      if (event?.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED){
           Log.d(TAG, "Source: ${event!!.source}") --> Source is null
      }
 }

   override fun onServiceConnected() {
    val info = AccessibilityServiceInfo()
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC
    info.notificationTimeout = 400
    info.packageNames = null
    serviceInfo = info
   }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <service
        android:name=".AccessibilityService"
        android:label="Accessibility Test"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accesibility_service_config" />
    </service>
```

accesibility_service_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:description="@string/accesibility_description"
 android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged"
 android:notificationTimeout="100"
 android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"/>
```

In other phone models the service works correctly and I get the info.

What can I do to get AccessibilityNodeInfo data?

Comment: same problem here